# textFieldShouldEndEditing not fire when users switch in another UItxextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

i have this code for textFieldShouldEndEditing:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   NSDecimalNumber *testIfNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[textField text]];
   if (![testIfNumber isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]])
   {
       NSLog(@"%@",[testIfNumber stringValue]);
       [[self labelTotal]setText:[self getTotalforRate:[expenseCategorySelected categoryRate] forAmmountField:textField]];

   }


}
```

Now my problem is that in my ViewController I have two or more textField and when a user goes directly from one to another textField this method is not fired.

Is there a method or a way to know when I'm going from a textField to another?
Thx.

Comment: Do you implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol ? did you set each text field's delegate to be your view controller's instance ?

Comment: `textField.delegate = self` Did you add this for two textfield?

Comment: Yes i have added but i not have find a way for use that when users switch between textFields. If Anyone can suggest a code sulutions would be appreciated

Comment: goes directly  means tap to next textfield or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong... `textFieldShouldEndEditing` is not for this purpose.
Just using `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: Thx the two method are very similar and i not have seen the diferent name thx alot.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this if u dont get

```
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>//heare set the delegate

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 200, 35)];
     UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, 200, 35)];
     UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 125, 200, 35)];

     textField1.placeholder = @"I am 1st field";
     textField2.placeholder = @"I am 2nd field";
     textField3.placeholder = @"I am 3rd field";

     //set the delegate for all text fields
     textField1.delegate = self;
     textField2.delegate = self;
     textField3.delegate = self;

     textField1.tag = 100;
     textField2.tag = 200;
     textField3.tag = 300;

     [self.view addSubview:textField1];
     [self.view addSubview:textField2];
     [self.view addSubview:textField3];
  }

   //implement the delegate methods

   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {

     if(textField.tag == 100)
     {
       NSLog(@"i am end editing -> %@",textField.text);
     }
     else if (textField.tag == 200)
    {
       NSLog(@"i am end editing -> %@",textField.text);
    }
     else if (textField.tag == 300)
    {
        NSLog(@"i am end editing -> %@",textField.text);
    }   
  }
```

Hope this helps u .. :)

Comment: With  Fry i have find my error but your comment can be very usefull for other things thx alot

Comment: i don't know about down vote... i have added +1 me now.